# start new activity intent error

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Hello I have 2 activities on my app and I want to be able to switch between them by clicking button when I tried my code I got error:

> 03-27 22:27:08.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9051): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.tdgame.dorbt12.MAIN }

my code is:

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent open = new Intent("com.tdgame.dorbt12.MAIN");
    startActivity(open);
}
```

the two activities names is: Main and Must

Comment: Have you added `com.price.dor.MAIN` to the manifest?

Comment: Can you give the package name of activity with name also.

Comment: yea i add it to the menifest

Comment: and its the right package name and activity name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't added `com.price.dor.MAIN`  in your Manifest.

Try setting the Activity like this as you are identifying activity based on the intent filter

```
  <activity
            android:name=".Main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.tdgame.dorbt12.MAIN" />  //required
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

you need intent filter Action tag because your passing intent using that.

```
 Intent open = new Intent("com.tdgame.dorbt12.MAIN");
```

Comment: thanks man I did add it to the manifest but I had mistake in the package name.

Comment: @dorbt12 I told initially to check the package name.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
Intent open = new Intent(currentActivitiy.this, destinationActivity.class);
startActivity(open);
```

Comment: Although your answer is correct, it doesn't provide solution to his problem

Comment: @Pragnani You're right, but in this case it's better to use normal intent instead of intent filter.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the syntax of your intent be a little bit different?
I usually write:

```
Intent open = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
```

where `SecondActivity` is the name of the Activity that you want to run.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
            Intent open  = new Intent(Main.this, Must.class);
            startActivity(open);
```

Add

```
                            <activity android:name=".Must" />
```

before closing `application` in you manifest